# function if more elements with same class in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, viewport, fadein

I want to fade in an element only when it's visible in the viewport. To do this, I'm using a `isOnScreen()` function. It works fine, but only with one element, and if more elements with the same class are on the page, it works only with the first one.

How can I use the function `isOnScreen()` for all the elements on page?

For example, I have an element `.quote` at the beginning and one at the end of the page. The first element works fine, the element at the bottom not.

I've tried to use `$('.quote').each(function() {` and inside `isOnScreen()'` but it doesn't work.

**EDIT**

I found the solution, see my own answer below.

```js
$.fn.isOnScreen = function(){

        var win = $(window);

        var viewport = {
            top : win.scrollTop(),
            left : win.scrollLeft()
        };
        viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
        viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

        var bounds = this.offset();
        bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
        bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

        return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));

    };

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        if ($('.quote-container').isOnScreen()) {
            $('.quote').addClass('fade-in');
        } else {
            $('.quote').removeClass('fade-in');
        }
    });
```

```css
.main-container {
  height: 2000px;
}
.quote-container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 0;
}
.quote {
    font-size: 175%;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 35px 215px;
}
.page-content {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin: 0;
}
.page-content p {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 230px;
    font-size: 220%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.big {
  height: 1000px;
}
.little {
  height: 700px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

.fade-in {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-out 1;
    -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-out 1;
    animation:fadeIn ease-out 1;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration:1.6s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1.6s;
    animation-duration:1.6s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="page-content little">
    <p>Page Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="quote-container">
    <p class="quote">Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="page-content big">
    <p>Page Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="quote-container">
    <p class="quote">Dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="page-content little">
    <p>Page Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just solved using the answer of Luis Serrano with some little changes.

```
  $('.quote-container').each(function() {
    if ($(this).isOnScreen()) {
        if ($(this).children('.fade-in').length < 1) {
        $(this).children().toggleClass('fade-in');
      }
    }
  });
```

In this way `.quote` will fade in only once and only when in viewport.

Comment: Cool! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$('.quote-container').each(function() {
  $('.quote').toggleClass('fade-in', $(this).isOnScreen());
});
```

This will call your `isOnScreen` method on each `.quote-container` elements, and will toggle the class to true/false on `.quote` based on the returned value.

That assuming that the item you want to be within the viewport is `.quote-container` and the multiple nodes where you want to add/remove the `fade-in` class have a `.quote` class. I understood that was the case by reading your `if` block, although the name of the classes is kind of confusing so I might have misunderstood. If so, let me know and I'll adapt the answer.

Comment: Yes, I just want that when a `.quote-container` is in the viewport, the `.quote` inside it fades in.
The problem with your answer is that it works only with the last element this time. And every time I scroll the page. It gives to the `.quote` a kind of "blinking" effect. I should put it into my `$(window).scroll` function, right? Or I misunderstood something?